# Create a thread on another PC in a local network

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, server, scalability

I am going to create a MMO server using bare C++.

The main disadvantage of this language is the fact that a program is executed on a single PC and can not be scaled between multiple PCs as easily as java programs.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to start a new thread on another PC so that if there were too many clients for a single PC to handle, another local PC could help.

For now, I have a code like this, which starts a new thread for each client on my PC.

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc, &hMutex, 0, NULL);
```

Is it possible to reduce CPU load of my PC by executing new threads on other PCs in the local network?

Comment: Use the same approach as in java xD

Comment: No, you can't run threads on another PC for some fundamental reasons - for one, different PCs do not share their RAM, while threads do.

Comment: @wilddev Well, Java has RMI.

Comment: @immibis so a distance server which managed thread launch from another PC. The approach has to be same : have a distance server which launch local thread by receiving order of a distance PC

Comment: What operating system?  If Windows, DCOM might provide a solution.  (Although, as noted, it won't be a different *thread*, it will be a different *process*.)

Comment: @Garf365 RMI makes it *really* convenient, and as far as I know there isn't a similar library for C++, nor does it seem feasible to create one.

Comment: @MartinBonner : How is that even an answer :)

Comment: @immibis I totally agree with you, RMI makes it really convenient. I don't know any similar library for C++, but I pretty sure that is feasible to create one. But the effort should be really hard, specially for supporting remote operating system and remote available resources.

Comment: @Geek:  It's a comment, not an answer.  Also there is a view (with which I have much sympathy) "If COM is the answer, you are asking the wrong question."

Comment: @MartinBonner DCOM makes cross-machine COM calls almost as easy as direct COM calls, just as RMI does for Java method calls. *However*, a direct COM call is still a hassle, whereas a Java method call isn't.

Comment: Hmm, with the help of ATL, DCOM is almost a transparent operation... But Windows servers have other problems. Anyway, IMHO DCOM has **nothing** to do with scalability.

Comment: *a program is executed on a single PC and can not be scaled between multiple PCs as easily as java programs* exact, c++ programs cannot be writen in java and a single program **whatever the language** can only run on one single CPU. *[is it] possible to start a new thread on another PC ?* no because of the definition of a **thread**. *Is it possible to reduce CPU load of my PC by executing new threads on other PCs in the local network?* of course it is! Just start a server on the other machine and pass it a message at socket level containing the information to process.